# Maximan directional derivative of a function is constant on circle of radius $R$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $a,b, R > 0$ and let $F(x,y) = \ln [ a(x^2 + y^2)^b ] $. I
>   want to prove that the maximal directional derivative of $F$ is
>   $\mathbf{constant}$ along any circle of radius $R$ centered at
>   $(0,0)$.

Here, do they mean only along the contour of the circle? this is a bit confusing, but assuming so, we have that

$$ \nabla F = \left( \frac{ 2 ab x }{x^2+y^2}, \frac{ 2ab y }{x^2+y^2} \right)   $$

along any direction $\mathbf{u}$, we maximal derivative is

$$ || \nabla F ||  = 2ab \sqrt{ \frac{ x^2 }{(x^2+y^2)^2 } + \frac{ y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} } = 2ab \frac{1}{R} \in \mathbb{R}$$

which is what we wanted.

Is this what the question is asking us to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks perfect, except ...
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
F(x,y) &=& \ln [ a(x^2 + y^2)^b ]
\\ &=&\ln a +b\ln(x^2+y^2)
\end{eqnarray*}$$

So $a$ should not be present in the expression for the gradient